# Ansible Variables in a varible

Tags: variables, ansible, roles, var

im trying to find a aternative for this as the below hasnt worked:
auth_combos:

```
 - {Athlone:
   - {DB_USERNAME: 'dcom'}
   - {DB_PASSWORD: 'aaaaaa'}}

 - {Santa Clara:
    - {DB_USERNAME: 'dcom'}
    - {DB_PASSWORD: 'bbbbbb'}}

 - {MSDP:
   - {DB_USERNAME: 'dcom'}
   - {DB_PASSWORD: 'ccccc}}
```

im trying to call the host (ie Athlone) in the library and then in turn it gets its username and password so that i can then access the host. the above is done in roles/var.yml.
any help or ideas ?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve... Maybe [host variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#host-variables) can help?

Answer (score 0):

A better practice is to use the `inventory` file to declare your variables

```
[machines]
Athlone DB_USERNAME=dcom DB_PASSWORD=aaaaaa
Santa Clara DB_USERNAME=dcom DB_PASSWORD=bbbbbb
MSDP DB_USERNAME=dcom DB_PASSWORD=ccccc
```

Hence, in the role you can directly refer to it by `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD`

Comment: i plan on putting roles/var into the vault and encrypting it, hence it is not in the inventory

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is host or group specific vars stored in [group_vars or host_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data) folders, which can be encrypted according to [Vault docunentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html#what-can-be-encrypted-with-vault)

Answer (score 0):

i have figured it out if anyone wants it:

DB_HOST: '"Athlone" "MSDP" "SantaClara"'
DB_USER:
  Athlone: 'dcom'
  MSDP: 'dcom'
  SantaClara: 'dcom'

DB_PASS:
  Athlone: 'aaaa'
  MSDP: 'cccc'
  SantaClara: 'bbbbb'